# React / Wepback 2 - Using Higher Order Components in routes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-2

I have a React app that uses React Router. My old routes use to look like this:

```
const ComponentRoutes = (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={LandingPage} />
    <Route path='/dashboard' component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)} />
  </Route>
);
```

RequireAuth is a HOC that only allows the user to go to Dashboard if they have the right credentials.

Now I am using Webpack 2 and I had to refactor my routes to this:

```
const componentRoutes = {
  component: App,
  path: '/',
  indexRoute: { component: LandingPage },
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./components/dashboard')
          .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

How do I add the RequireAuth HOC back into the routes?

Comment: I haven't tried that specifc router syntax, but I would say that you can wrap `module.default` with your HOC and it should work, the HOC is a simple function over a component.

Comment: That worked, thanks!